# Prepareforsegue vs Storing in Dictionary. Using Swift, Xcode 6. Best practice?

Tags: ios7, swift, xcode6

I'd like to know why use prepareforsegue if you can just store the data in a Dictionary?

It seems easier if you just initialize the dictionary in the first view controller and add/edit/remove from it in the subsequent view controllers.

I'd like to know if this is a bad practice or will either work just fine?

I'm currently using a dictionary to pass data forward and backwards to view controllers.

Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: How do you get the dictionary from one view controller to the next?

Comment: It autocompletes the dictionary name when I'm on a different view controller's file, then I just add/edit as I normally would. I'm making a single view application. I'm assuming it's because the vc's are like a deck of cards and I'm just getting data from what's previously initialized. But I honestly don't know if I'm starting a bad habit. It's my first app. Prepareforsegue seems unnecessary but I may be missing a major point.

Comment: When Xcode autocompletes it, the dictionary has to be imported to the class. It is extremely important that you understand how and where data is added to your classes. Otherwise you will get in big trouble soon. Read about Model-View-Controller or Model-View-ViewModel.

Comment: Will do, but do you think that it's an acceptable approach for a simple single view application? I don't know why an app would be rejected, but is could be one of those reasons?

Comment: It's not about the Apple review. It's about maintainable code. If you want to understand the code you write today you need to understand it today and follow good coding styles.